# How to ignore negative and zero values in TableView?

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code:

```
costCol_.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getCost()));
table_.getItems().addAll(SomeEnumType.values());



@FXML
private TableView<SomeEnumType> table_;
@FXML
private TableColumn<7, Number> costCol_;
```

Some values in costCol can be 0/-1 and currently (from `SomeEnumType.getCost()`), they are shown as 0 or -1.
I do not want to display them as 0 rather as an empty cell. Is it possible?
I have  checked SimpleIntegerBase and from what I understood, the values returned are from the `get()` method which returns `int`.

Is it possible to do this without me converting the type to `String`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can `SomeEnumType` be negative, or, what do you mean with negative?

Comment: SomeEnumType has a getCost() method which returns an int. This is my concern, sorry if I am not clear on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Use a cell factory (in addition to the existing cell value factory) to change the way the value is displayed:

```
costCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<SomeEnumType, Number>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            int value = item.intValue();
            if (value <= 0) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(Integer.toString(value));
            }
        }
    }
});
```